# How can I pass a jinja2 object to a jquery function as parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, jinja2

In my python script, I have something like this

```
students = getStudent()  
return render_template('index.html', students = students)
```

students is a list of student, and each student has attributes like name, id, gpa, ....

In index.html, I have a selection like this

```
 <select class="form-control" onchange="changeStudent">
     {% for student in students %}
         <option>{{student.name}}</option>
     {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

Now I want to implement a jquery function that can do can for example print out the student information if that student is selected.

```
function changeStudent(student) {
    alert(student.name)
}
```

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the script in the same page with the html document ? Or it’s is in a external file?

Comment: In the current implementation, the script in external, but if it is easier to do within the html document, I can change that.

Comment: Yes , it easier to do it in the same file

Comment: that's just normal JavaScript :P Not anything jQuery related

Comment: If it’s in the same file you can call the variable name the same way you do in Html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an inline `<script type="application/javascript">` element in your HTML you can just drop it straight in there.

Just make sure the object in your context is a JSON formatted string and that the data is genuinely [safe](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping).

**view.py**

```
import json
def index_view():
    students = json.dumps(getStudent())
    return render_template('index.html', students = students)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="application/javascript">
      var students = {{ students|safe }};
      // do your thang...    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```